# Using discard in Sourcetree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I would like to know if I right click on an unstaged file and click on discard, will that remove the file from my folder or will it just "undo" the changes I made but leave the file alone. Also will it affect my files on bitbucket. I'm worried that if I discard the file it will delete it and then I would have problems pulling my files down from bitbucket.

I'm sorry if these are silly questions.

Answer (score 2):

`discard` will only remove the local file changes that you have made to a specific file. This will put the file back to the state it was in the last commit. `remove` completely removes the file from version control which will result in git no longer watching the file. This would result in changes made to the file not being reflected in your Sourcetree.